# Compile Mono for Android ARM7

Tags: android, compilation, mono, android-ndk, arm

I have different C# applications which should run on an Android device. (ARMv7)
(I don’t want to write an app using Xamarin.)

First I tried to compile mono 3.2.0 and mono 2.11.4 with two different toolchains (codesourcery and ndk-standalone-toolchain)

> ./configure –disable-mcs-build –host=arm-linux-androideabi –target=arm-linux-androideabi –disable-boehm --with-sigaltstack=no CFLAGS="-march=arm7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon"

The compilation process is finished successfully but the binaries are not executable. 
(chmod is 777)

The output of “file mono-sgen” is
 ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.16, not stripped

When I want to execute the mono-sgen:

> ./mono-sgen
>   sh: ./mono-sgen: No such file or directory

I also tried to build it with the scratchbox like mentioned in the mono documentation but it also didn't work. Any Ideas or hints?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?  Did you have to build with the android tool chain??